# Compiler error when using CRTP with static_assert

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, crtp, static-assert

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    static constexpr int x_base = Derived::x_derived;
    //static_assert(x_base > 1, "Oops");
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {
    static  constexpr int x_derived = 5 ;
};

Base<Derived> obj;
```

This compiles fine on gcc but if I uncomment the `static_assert` line, it complains that

```
error: incomplete type 'Derived' used in nested name specifier
static constexpr int x_base = Derived::x_derived;
```

I tried it with different versions of gcc from 4.9 to 5.3 and I get the same error (you can try it on godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/g/v0g9nX)). clang refuses to compile it even without the `static_assert`, and complains that

```
error: no member named 'x_derived' in 'Derived'
static constexpr int x_base = Derived::x_derived;
```

Which compiler is correct (if any)? 
Is there a nice way to fix the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accessing nested names requires the class to be complete, but `Derived` isn't complete here yet:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    static constexpr int x_base = Derived::x_derived;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^
};
```

so the code is ill-formed.

There are a few workarounds. First, you can separately just pass in the value as a template argument:

```
template <typename Derived, int x_derived>
struct Base {
    static constexpr int x_base = x_derived;
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived, 5> { };
```

Second, if possible (e.g. you don't need `x_derived` to declare any members), you can move the value into a function to delay its instantiation:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
    static constexpr int x_base() {
        static_assert(Derived::x_derived > 1, "Oops");
        return Derived::x_derived;
    }

};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {
    static constexpr int x_derived = 5;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Barry. So, if I understood you correctly, the fact that gcc accepts the code without static_assert is a compiler bug, and clang is correct in rejecting it?

Comment: @toth gcc doesn't reject it until you actually use it anywhere - so it's just a little friendlier in that respect. But it's not really meaningful to just declare a variable you never use - so it correctly rejects it where it's important.

Comment: but gcc does let me use it, as long as it's not in a static_assert. E.g., https://godbolt.org/g/rfbH5c (while clang continues to reject the code). So one of the compilers must be wrong, any idea which?

Comment: @toth gcc should reject it.